# need to show changed text after comparing two strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have two strings:

1 string = "stackoverflow"

2 string = "stackoverflow is good"

I want to show: "stackoverflow `is good`".

"is good" should be highlighted with some background-color..

how is it possible to do with c#?

Comment: what output; asp.net? winforms? console?

Comment: Interesting question. How do you want to handle deleted text and changed text? Could be nice for the person who is attempting to answer your question to know.

Comment: output -> image on asp.net webpage.

Comment: Is it a fixed requirement to use an image? It would be easier from a development perspective to keep it as text and wrap the difference in a span with a backgroundcolor attribute set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First format all the text in the highlight-color then search for the "stackoverflow" and format it back to the normal format. This way you don't have to mess with the problem of finding something but formatting something else.

For technical details I have to know, what kind of control you use to display the text (Textbox, Rtf, Html).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string strComplete = "stackoverflow is good, I mean, stackoverflow is really good";
    string strSearch = "stackoverflow";
    Console.WriteLine(FormatString(strComplete, strSearch));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string FormatString(string strComplete, string strSearch)
{
    string strSpannedSearch = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "", strSearch, "");
    return strComplete.Replace(strSearch, strSpannedSearch);            
}
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment. You can use spans around your words and then assign classes to them. Format your complete <p> with the class "highlighted" and the wrap the "overflow" with <span class="normal">overflow</span>. You can do it with IndexOf.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out something on these lines

```
string s1 = "Hello";
string s2 = "Hello world";

s2=  s2.Replace(s1, "");
Bitmap bmap = new Bitmap(150, 25);
Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(bmap);

graphic.DrawString(s1, new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 8), new SolidBrush(Color.White), new PointF());
graphic.DrawString(s2, new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 8), new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), new PointF());
bmap.Save("myimage.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: your solution is great! but i want to get out image like it looks like in a browser. not just a string. and a changed text should be marked with some color for easier overview. please help!